# Фильтрация нецензурных слов в сообщениях(комментариях) на сайте.Django

Tags: python, html, django

Всем привет!
Делаю сайт на Django, где у пользователей есть возможность оставлять комментарии и мне нужно сделать фильтрацию нецензурных слов в этих комментариях. Я покопался в интернетах, но ничего вроде не нашел как это реализовать в Django.
Надеюсь кто-нибудь поможет)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы не знаете, как просмотреть пользовательские сообщения? ВЫ делаете мессенджер?

Comment: Скорее всего таких библиотек нет, а если и есть, то с фильтрацией к английскому. Единственно пока , что мне приходит в голову это создать таблицу с непристойными выражениями , словами и проверять каждый комментарий перед записью, что вынуждает Вас иметь хорошие знания в области алгоритмов. Я бы реализовывал это через django signals с методом pre_save, таким образом отменял запись.

Comment: @SmartBeetle
Я делаю парсер сайтов в поисковой выдаче. Там у меня есть возможность просмотра полной инфы по парсу на отдельной странице, где юзеры могут оставлять отзывы и комментарии по сайту. И вот фильтр этих комментариев хотел бы реализовать)

Comment: @WilteRatenau я бы не отменял, а просто отображал бы эти комменты только для этих пользователей. Пусть думают что сообщение отправлено и будет отображено всем, чем ищут способы обхода. ибо кто захочет, тот напишет нецензурщину несмотря на запреты

Comment: @ZaArs в зависимости от того, сколько могут принимать в комментариях участников. Допустим если это соц.сець, тогда ваше предложение логично. Однако если в комментариях принимает 2-3 человека и это рабочий процесс, тогда не получится.

Comment: почему же?.....

Answer (score 0):

Вот простенький вариант.Он не будет обрабатывать такой вариант: м!а!т!.

```
def filter_message(message: str):
variants = ['mat', 'abc', 'def', 'no', 'filter'] # непристойные выражения
ln = len(variants)
filtred_message = ''
string = ''
pattern = '*' # чем заменять непристойные выражения
for i in message:
    string += i
    string2 = string.lower()
    
    flag = 0
    for j in variants:
        if not string2 in j:
            flag += 1
        if string2 == j:
            filtred_message += pattern * len(string)
            flag -= 1
            string = ''
            
    if flag == ln:
        filtred_message += string
        string = ''
        
if string2 != '' and string2 not in variants:
    filtred_message += string
elif string2 != '':
    filtred_message += pattern * len(string)
    
return filtred_message
```

Пару тестов:

## print(filter_message('matdef lkjshlkjg abc'))

output: ****** lkjshlkjg ***

## print(filter_message('no mats'))

output: ** ***s

## print(filter_message('12345'))

output: 12345

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает)
Долго не заходил на стак, не видел ваш ответ)